# what will be a typical scene graph looks like?

Tags: opengl, graphics, directx, opengl-es-2.0

I am wondering what will be a typical scene graph looks like?

Does the classic format like OBJ, OFF corresponds to scene graph?

Comment: I tried to give an answer, but your question is a bit vague. Could you clarify a bit ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No they don't. OBJ and OFF are just mesh formats.

A scene graph is generally a more high-level structure used to represent hierarchical relations between objects composing a scene. 
It's useful for several reasons such as perform scene nodes relative transformations, partitioning the space...

I suggest you to have a look at both [OpenSceneGraph](http://www.openscenegraph.org/) and [Ogre3D](http://www.ogre3d.org/) frameworks. Both organizes their scenes using a graph.